# Showing $| \lambda_i | < 1 \implies \operatorname{tr}(A) - 1 < \det(A) <1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Prove that every eigenvalue of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ has modulus less than 1 if and only if 
>   $$
> \operatorname{tr}(A)-1
> < \det(A)
> <1.
> $$

I can prove the forward direction, but not through steps that can be reversed so I'm stuck on proving the other directing, i.e. assuming the inequality holds and proving that the eigenvalues have modulus less than 1.

I know $\operatorname{tr}(A)=\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$ and $\det(A) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2$, assuming the matrix has two eigenvalues.

Comment: How did you show the other direction you mention?

Comment: Since the matrix is real, the roots of its characteristic polynomial - the eigenvalues - come in conjugate pairs. Since $1>\det A = \lambda_1\lambda_2 = |\lambda_1|^2 = |\lambda_2|^2$, we're done. Am I missing something?

Comment: Only if they are nonreal @Liam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**One way:**

Let $a,b$ be eigenvalues, then we have to prove $$a+b-1\leq ab$$

but this is the same as $$0\leq (a-1)(b-1)$$ which is true if $a,b$ are real.

If $a,b$ are nonreal then $b=\overline{a}$ then we have to prove $$0\leq (a-1)\overline{(a-1)} = |a-1|^2$$ which is also true.

And $$\det A\leq |\det A| = |ab| < 1$$

**Vice versa:** Since $$0\leq (a-1)(b-1)$$ is true, then if $a,b $ are bot real then both are $>1$ or $<1$. Say both are $>1$. Then $ab>1$ which is not true since $ab = \det A <1$. So both are $<1$.

If $a,b$ are nonreal, then $b=\overline{a}$, so $$|a|^2 =|b|^2 = ab = \det A <1$$ 
 and we are done.

Comment: Why is $(a-1)(b-1) \ge 0$? Consider $a = -1$ and $b = 2$.

Comment: But $|a|$ and  $|b|$ are not smaller than 1 then @ViktorGlombik

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\operatorname{tr} A - 1 - \det A = (1-\lambda_1)(\lambda_2 - 1).$$
Also, the eigenvalues can be complex and $A$ must have have precisely two eigenvalues. Note that these inequalities can hold when both of them are complex.